# convert unparameterized Java 1.4 Collection to parameterized Scala Sequence

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

How can I convert a java 1.4 Collection to a Scala Seq?

I am trying to pass a java-collection to a scala method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

// list is a 1.4 java.util.ArrayList
// repository.getDir is Java legacy code
val list = repository.getDir(...)
perform(list)
def perform(entries: List[SVNDirEntry]) = ...
```

I always receive this error:

```
type mismatch; found : java.util.Collection[?0] where type ?0 required: List   
[SVNDirEntry]
```

So I guess I have to create the parameterized Sequence myself as Scala is only able to create an unparameterized Iterable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to make sure that `list` has the type `java.util.List[SVNDirEntry]`. To do this, use a cast:

```
list.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[SVNDirEntry]]
```

After that, the implicit conversion will be resolved for you if you import the `JavaConversions` object. An implicit conversion to a Scala sequence exists in the `JavaConversions` object. See the following example with a list of strings being passed to a method that expects a Scala sequence:

```
scala> val jvlist: java.util.List[_] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
jvlist: java.util.List[_] = []

scala> jvlist.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[String]]
res0: java.util.List[String] = []

scala> import collection.JavaConversions._                                                                          
import collection.JavaConversions._                                                                                 

scala> def perform(scalaseq: Seq[String]) = println("ok")                                    
perform: (scalaseq: scala.collection.Seq[String])Unit                                                   

scala> perform(res0)                                                                                                
ok
```

These conversions do not copy the elements - they simply construct a wrapper around a Java collection. Both versions point to the same underlying data. Thus, there is no implicit conversion in `JavaConversions` to immutable Scala lists from mutable Java lists, because that would enable changing the contents of a Scala collection that is guaranteed to be immutable.

In short - prefer `Seq[...]` to `List[...]` when defining parameters for methods if you can live with a less specific interface (as in `perform` above). Or write your own function that does the conversion by copying the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the legacy collection down to the target type. Something along the lines of:

```
perform(list.asInstanceOf[List[SVNDirEntry]])
```

Comment: Only you are casting the Scala collection, not the Java one.